# LibGDX Cut texture with an angle

Tags: libgdx

Suppose I have a `Texture` and I want to split it in half on a line rotated with a given angle.

[image]

In result I expect to get two `Texture` objects with the corresponding halfs of the original texture. Would be very nice if it could be done with some kind of transformation/masking so that I wouldn't have to store copies of two new textures at runtime.

Is this even possible?

I tried to work around `Gdx.gl.glSsisors()` but couldn't make it work as it requires screen coords to be passed as parameters.
Also I tried to go with `Pixmap` but couldn't find anything that would indicate it's even possible.

Comment: You can do anything with Pixmap, but that route would require two Textures loaded. To clip a sprite diagonally, scissors won't help since it only does screen-aligned rectangles. I think the best way to do this would be with a shader. Some people on the libGDX discord were discussing this exact problem in the #shaders section about a month or two ago. You might try there and see if it lets you scroll back far enough to see their solution and ask them about it.

Comment: They were discussing it on Oct.17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by manually calculating two skewed quads and render those using a `SpriteBatch`.

Cutting a sprite along angle `angle` we get a directional vector representing the cut by

```
public void cut(float angle) {
    Vector2 d = (new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f)).rotate(angle);
```

if we also define the four corners for the [UV Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping) of the `Texture`, along with the center and one vector `la` going `d` away from the center and `lb` going -`d`

```
Vector2 c = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
Vector2 la = (new Vector2(d)).scl( 1.0f).add(c);
Vector2 lb = (new Vector2(d)).scl(-1.0f).add(c);

Vector2 tl = new Vector2(0, 1);
Vector2 tr = new Vector2(1, 1);
Vector2 bl = new Vector2(0, 0);
Vector2 br = new Vector2(1, 0);
```

we can then calculate the intersection of the cut

```
Vector2 i1 = new Vector2();
Vector2 i2 = new Vector2();

if (Intersector.intersectSegments(c, la, tl, tr, i1) || Intersector.intersectSegments(c, lb, tl, tr, i1))
    i2.set(1.0f - i1.x, 1.0f - i1.y);
else {
    if (Intersector.intersectSegments(c, la, tl, bl, i1) || Intersector.intersectSegments(c, lb, tl, bl, i1))
        i2.set(1.0f - i1.x, 1.0f - i1.y);
}
```

At this point we know that one half of the cut will consist of vertices `i1`, `i2` and two of `tl`, `tr`, `bl` and `br`, so if we sort them by angle away from the cut and then take the first 4 from `i1` we get the vertices required to build the skewed quad:

```
Vector2[] vertexList = new Vector2[] {
        tl, tr, bl, br, i1, i2
};

Array<VertexAngle> vas = new Array<>();
for (Vector2 v : vertexList) {
    Vector2 vd = (new Vector2(v)).sub(c);
    float a = d.angle(vd);
    VertexAngle va = new VertexAngle();
    va.v = v;
    va.a = a;
    vas.add(va);
}

vas.sort(new Comparator<VertexAngle>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(VertexAngle a, VertexAngle b) {
        return Float.compare(a.a, b.a);
    }
});

Array<Vector2> nv = new Array<>();
for (VertexAngle va : vas)
    nv.add(va.v);

int index = nv.indexOf(i1, true);
```

The a float array containing the vertex data for the draw call can be constructed and rendered with a call to `draw` on `SpriteBatch`.

For example:

[image]

Full source code for the above example is:

```
package com.bornander.sandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class SandboxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;
    CutTexture cutTexture;

    public static class CutTexture
    {
        public static class VertexAngle {
            public Vector2 v;
            public float a;
        }

        public static class CutHalf {
            public float[] vertices = new float[4 * 5];

            public void translate(float x, float y) {
                for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 5) {
                    vertices[i + 0] += x;
                    vertices[i + 1] += y;
                }
            }
        }

        public Vector2 position = new Vector2();
        public Vector2 driftDirection = new Vector2();
        public float drift = 0.0f;
        public Texture source;
        public CutHalf halfA = new CutHalf();
        public CutHalf halfB = new CutHalf();

        public void cut(float angle) {
            Vector2 d = (new Vector2(1.0f, 0.0f)).rotate(angle);
            Vector2 c = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
            driftDirection.set(d).rotate(90.0f);
            Vector2 la = (new Vector2(d)).scl( 1.0f).add(c);
            Vector2 lb = (new Vector2(d)).scl(-1.0f).add(c);

            Vector2 tl = new Vector2(0, 1);
            Vector2 tr = new Vector2(1, 1);
            Vector2 bl = new Vector2(0, 0);
            Vector2 br = new Vector2(1, 0);

            Vector2 i1 = new Vector2();
            Vector2 i2 = new Vector2();

            if (Intersector.intersectSegments(c, la, tl, tr, i1) || Intersector.intersectSegments(c, lb, tl, tr, i1))
                i2.set(1.0f - i1.x, 1.0f - i1.y);
            else {
                if (Intersector.intersectSegments(c, la, tl, bl, i1) || Intersector.intersectSegments(c, lb, tl, bl, i1))
                    i2.set(1.0f - i1.x, 1.0f - i1.y);
            }

            Vector2[] vertexList = new Vector2[] {
                    tl, tr, bl, br, i1, i2
            };

            Array<VertexAngle> vas = new Array<>();
            for (Vector2 v : vertexList) {
                Vector2 vd = (new Vector2(v)).sub(c);
                float a = d.angle(vd);
                VertexAngle va = new VertexAngle();
                va.v = v;
                va.a = a;
                vas.add(va);
            }

            vas.sort(new Comparator<VertexAngle>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(VertexAngle a, VertexAngle b) {
                    return Float.compare(a.a, b.a);
                }
            });

            Array<Vector2> nv = new Array<>();
            for (VertexAngle va : vas)
                nv.add(va.v);

            int index = nv.indexOf(i1, true);
            int idx = 0;
            int lastIndex = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                lastIndex = (index + j) % nv.size;
                Vector2 vertex = nv.get(lastIndex);
                float width = source.getWidth();
                float height = source.getWidth();
                float fx2 = position.x + width * vertex.x - width / 2.0f;
                float fy2 = position.y + height * vertex.y - height / 2.0f;

                halfA.vertices[idx++] = fx2;
                halfA.vertices[idx++] = fy2;
                halfA.vertices[idx++] = Color.WHITE_FLOAT_BITS;
                halfA.vertices[idx++] = vertex.x;
                halfA.vertices[idx++] = 1.0f - vertex.y;
            }

            idx = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                Vector2 vertex = nv.get((lastIndex + j) % nv.size);
                float width = source.getWidth();
                float height = source.getWidth();
                float fx2 = position.x + width * vertex.x - width / 2.0f;
                float fy2 = position.y + height * vertex.y - height / 2.0f;

                halfB.vertices[idx++] = fx2;
                halfB.vertices[idx++] = fy2;
                halfB.vertices[idx++] = Color.WHITE_FLOAT_BITS;
                halfB.vertices[idx++] = vertex.x;
                halfB.vertices[idx++] = 1.0f - vertex.y;
            }
        }

        public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {

            float dx = driftDirection.x * drift;
            float dy = driftDirection.y * drift;

            halfA.translate(dx, dy);
            halfB.translate(-dx, -dy);

            batch.draw(source, halfA.vertices, 0, 20);
            batch.draw(source, halfB.vertices, 0, 20);

            halfA.translate(-dx, -dy);
            halfB.translate(dx, dy);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void create () {
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 800 * aspectRatio);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2.0f, camera.viewportHeight / 2.0f, 0.0f);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));

        Gdx.gl.glCullFace(0);
        cutTexture = new CutTexture();
        cutTexture.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2.0f, camera.viewportHeight / 2.0f);
        cutTexture.source = texture;
        cutTexture.cut(0);
    }

    float[] cutAngles = new float[] { 0.0f, -22.5f, -45.0f, -12.0f, -75.0f, -90.0f};
    int ai = 0;

    @Override
    public void render () {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE))
        {
            cutTexture.drift = 0.0f;
            cutTexture.cut(cutAngles[(ai++) % cutAngles.length]);
        }
        cutTexture.drift -= 64.0f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glCullFace(GL20.GL_NONE);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        cutTexture.render(batch);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```